# Returning boolean value if two sets share numbers

Tags: python

I want to write a function that returns true if two sets share some numbers and false (obviously) if they don't.

Here's what I have so far:

```
def contains(set1, set2):

    set1 = [5,2,9,1,3]
    set2 = [3,8,9,1,4]

    set_of_nums1, set_of_nums2 = set(set1), set(set2)

    for i in set1:
        if i in set2:
            return True

        return False

contains (set([5,2,9,1,3]), set([3,8,9,1,4]))
```

Should be working but I get no return. How come?

Comment: Why don't you just use set methods? This could be `return bool(set1 & set2)`. Also, why does your function ignore its inputs, and have you considered when the second `return` actually gets reached?

Comment: Didn't even know it existed, I'm a total beginner! :) But thanks for the hint. I don't know why it ignores the inputs.

Comment: ...because you immediately and explicitly replace them with a pair of lists?

Comment: @jonrsharpe ohhh....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just your indentation that's wrong. Your code right now only returns `True` if you have the first number of set1 in set 2, as it returns `True` in the first iteration of the loop if i is not in set2. Just fix it like this:

```
def contains(set1, set2):

    set1 = [5,2,9,1,3]
    set2 = [3,8,9,1,4]

    for i in set1:
        if i in set2:
            return True

    return False
```

however, as pointed out in the comments, this is not the most practical way to do it

It does make no sense, though, that you take 2 inputs and then completely override the values that they come with. Either you should declare the function like this:  `def contains():` and take no inputs, or you should remove those 2 lines changing the values of set1 and set2 before even using the ones passed as inputs.

Comment: You also haven't solved the problem that this function *completely ignores its inputs*.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but still won't return anything!

Comment: @Juls it does return for me

Comment: @Juls if you call the function the way you're calling it in the question its not gonna print anything, try adding print before it (`print contains([5,2,9,1,3], [3,8,9,1,4])`)

Answer (score 4):

for checking if sets share at least a single item could be, using [built in method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects), as @jonrsharpe pointed out in in comments:

```
if set1.intersection(set2):
  # share an element
```

Or using intersection operator (`&`)

```
if set1 & set2:
  # share an element
```

Comment: Or `not set1.isdisjoint(set2)`, because you don't actually need to build the intersection set.

Answer (score 0):

This is very fast, as it will stop iterating as soon as it finds a item that intersects.

The time complexity is in the worst case (if there is no intersection and it iterates trough the whole set): O(N), N being the number of elements in the smaller set.

```py
def any_intersection(set1: set, set2: set) -> bool:
    """
    Check if two sets have an intersection (its much more efficient than set.intersection() for big sets)

    Examples:

    >>> any_intersection({'a', 'b'}, {'c', 'd'})
    False
    >>> any_intersection({'a', 'b', 'c'}, {'c', 'd'})
    True
    """
    small_set, big_set = sorted((set1, set2), key=len)  # find the smaller set
    return any(map(big_set.__contains__, small_set))
```